# Postgres - repeat select over multiple tables and join

Tags: postgresql

A product we use stores the same data for different years in different tables - i.e. `Test2015`, `Test2016`, etc.  Unfortunately, I don't have any way to influence how the data is stored.

I currently have a working query that pulls the columns from the tables and unions the data into one data source (see psuedocode below) for easier analysis across years.

For now I only have a couple years of data, but over time we will be accumulating more data.  Is there any easy way to iterate this type of query without having to repeat lines of code?

Cheers,
Jonathon

```
WITH
  2015data AS (SELECT Name, Score, Year FROM Test2015),
  2016data AS (SELECT Name, Score, Year FROM Test2016)

SELECT * FROM 2015data

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM 2016data
```

Comment: If you're looking for a pure SQL solution, I think a good approach would be to write a stored procedure that accepts two parameters, a begin year and end year, that runs a query selecting the name of all tables in the current database and filters the table names between the begin and ends years. Then with the stored results of the table names you're interested in, loop through them and generate a dynamic query using UNION ALL between the tables you're interested in. Finally run the query and return the results. I could write you a MySQL solution but I don't have any postgresql experience.

Comment: Yep. Search for "dynamic SQL" and "plpgsql". Look up `execute` in particular.

Comment: If you don't need proper foreign keys, you can use table inheritance for this. Together with proper check constraints you can even make Postgres ignore "the other" tables when you query for a specific year: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no easy way to make this automatic. But when you say "union the data into one data source", do you mean that you create a view? If so, then you only have to update the view once a year to include the new table. If not, then I suggest you do just that:

```
CREATE VIEW TestAll AS
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT Name, Score, Year FROM Test2015) 2015data
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT Name, Score, Year FROM Test2016) 2016data;
  -- Add more years as the tables are created
```

Not ideal, but also not too difficult to maintain.

In your analysis you now simply use the `TestAll` view, like:

```
SELECT Name, avg(Score)
FROM TestAll
WHERE Year < date_trunc('year', CURRENT_DATE) - 2
GROUP BY Name;
```